# Testing the temperature of an open flame

Tags: classical-mechanics, thermodynamics, experimental-physics

How, and what device do you need, to obtain the exact temperature of an open flame? For the purpose of this question, you wanted to maintain 375 degrees. You can control the flame, but have no idea the temperature of it. A pyrometer is probably the best device, but the evenness of the heat distribution is important. What do you use? Can a aluminum plate distribute the heat evenly? Is there a pyrometer that can reside, and attach, on top of the aluminum plate, i.e glued to the surface? What are other solutions to this problem?

Comment: The temperature of a typical open flame can vary considerably in the volume of the flame. Do you want some kind of mean, the hottest spot, something else?

Comment: See other response for more info. The flame controlled, but may have hotspots. Is there something that I can even out the temperature over a surface as well as exactly measure the top surface temperature?

Answer (score 5):

A flame does not have a single temperature. The temperature at various points can be monitored using laser spectroscopy, or spectral measurements can determine the temperature of black-body emitters in the flame (soot particles). You will likely need a high degree of knowledge about the composition of the flame for these techniques, and probably this is not really what you want to be doing. More information on the problem you are trying to solve would be helpful.

Comment: The flame is a controlled natural gas feed. However, the temperature is not known. I am trying to regulate the temperature of the flame and have it spread evenly on (perhaps) an aluminum shelf / plate.

Comment: @PJAlla - So is it the temperature of the flame that matters, or the temperature of the plate? Measuring the temperature of a plate is pretty simple.

Comment: @Zephyr, of course the heat plate temperature is important, or maybe the thing(s) on that plate. So the **power** of that flame is relevant, not its temperature. But this is not easy to understand for amateurs. Try to convince a houswife that the temperature of the oven is not relevant, but the heat current into the pot with the turkey and the time

Comment: @Georg that is kinda my point - if you are trying to build a control loop to regulate the temperature of a hotplate, then measuring the temperature of the flame is a fairly irrelevant difficulty. (So long as the temperature is greater than the setpoint of course).

Comment: If someone builds such a heat plate using some electrical heater, he would not ask for the temperature of the heater wires in that heater, most people would not even know that those well above 1000 C. In case of a flame, not even knowing of a heat current, such ideas a produced.  What will Allen do, when he would measure higher temperatures in smaller flames?

Comment: @Georg, I agree.. that is why I am curious about what exactly PJAllan is trying to accomplish.

Comment: The temperature of the plate is the most important thing.

Comment: The idea is to control the temperature of the plate that causes the item on the plate to rise/fall. However, what do I need to effectively know the temperature of the top of the plate, then allowing me to adjust the flame to compensate for the delta of the object resting on the plate? What components are needed to create the "plate"?

Comment: The "power" of the flame is secondary. The plate w/ the correct pyrometer is what I am looking for. How do I measure the top of the plate accurately? What is the plate made of and how do I measure the temperature? The plate is not an electrical devices, i.e., a hotplate. I am looking for the "plate" solution.

Comment: @zephyr - Your comments are closer to the answer I am looking for. I mistakenly asked for the temperature of the flame. What I am looking for relates to the "plate". Regardless of the heat source, (and the heat source is separate from the plate), what material (copper, aluminum, etc.) can conduct the thermal transference of heat (from the original source, i.e., a flame) and what device can be added to the plate to measure the even distribution of said heat on the top of the plate?

Comment: Just a remark about aluminium: at 600 C it flash burns in air... Do not overheat your steak...

Answer (score 2):

As already stated a flame can have a wide range of temperatures depending on where you exactly measure it. As an example here is the rough temperature profile of a candle flame:

[image: Candle flame]

With a gas flame the temperature profile will be different but the general picture is similar. You can easily measure this profile with a Platinum or thermocouple thermometer that are needle shaped. If you are only interested in an average you can put a copper plate in the vicinity and measure the temperature of the copper plate and use that temperature to regulate your gas flow (might be very non-linear though).

Comment: Thanks. However, I really am interested in the "plate". What (I assume) metal can transfer the heat from the flame to record and maintain a specific temperature, evenly? What components can be placed together (as on object) to distribute (even) heat and display the exact temperature?

Comment: Your assumption might be too simple for this problem. As Georg pointed out correctly the temperature of a metal plate will be determined by the absorbed thermal energy. This is connected to the flame temperature but not equal to it. If you want an even heat distribution try with a material that has a high thermal conductivity like copper. If you want to maintain a specific temperature a material with a high specific heat, like water.

Comment: Good information. I can appreciate your and Georg's point of view. Maybe I need to rephrase the problem, for clarification. It is not the temperature of the flame I am concerned with, although this is how I posed the question. My apologies. I am interested in the plate, the thermal distribution, temperature measurement of the top side of the plate, the device used to determine the temperature and the process in which to affix a pryometer across the top of the plate. I am trying to control the exact temperature that the object that is placed on the top side of the plate.

Comment: @PJAllan: Ok, so you want to built a [hotplate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_plate)? Just look at a commercial one, they are not that rare in a lab. They use a simple PID controller and either an electrical or gas heater.

Comment: No, I do not want to build a hotplate. It is not the source for the heat, it is the containment / distribution and measurement of the temperature of the source of the heat. To be clearer, if I needed a surface temperature (of the plate) to be exactly 375 degrees when I place and object it, I want to make sure that the "plate" is 375 degrees. Buying or building a "hotplate" is not the solution to this problem. Creating the plate to distribute and read the exact temperature is the solution.

Comment: I do not want to build a hotplate. Not in the sense that it will have internal working components to supply the energy to heat it. I just want to know if there is a "plate" out there that can measure top surface temperature.

Comment: I guess I am looking for one of two things. First, is there a "plate" that does what I am looking for it to do? Or, what are the best materials for me to make this "plate"? - Thanks

Comment: @PJAllan: A relatively thick (5mm upwards) copper or aluminium plate together with a PT1000 temperature sensor and a PID controller should do the job.